# System.MissingMethodException Int32 System.Environment. get_CurrentManagedThreadId()

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

What could cause the following exception?

```
System.MissingMethodException Int32 System.Environment.get_CurrentManagedThreadId()
```

This method call seems to be generated by C# compiler for methods yielding `IEnumerable<>`.

.NET Framework v4.0 x86 is installed and the binary is compiled for v4.0 Any CPU.

Comment: This also pops up as "Method not found: `Int32.System.Environment.get_CurrentManagedThreadId()`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`CurrentManagedThreadId` is a .NET 4.5 property, so you will need 4.5 to run the code.
See [Iterator blocks, missing methods, and .NET 4.5](http://marcgravell.blogspot.de/2012/09/iterator-blocks-missing-methods-and-net.html) for an analysis of how this problem might occur.

**In short:**

If you build your application (targeted at .NET 4.0) on a system with .NET 4.5 installed, it will use 4.5 as basis for the compilation, because the .NET 4.0 Framework is always overwritten by .NET 4.5.

If your application then also uses `yield return`, it will fail on systems having only 4.0 installed because the implementation of this statement uses a new property when compiled for the 4.5 Framework.

To solve it, make sure your compiler system has the 4.0 reference assemblies.

Comment: I've been looking at this problem recently and noticed that a build server with 4.6.1 installed created code depending on `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` again. I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere online but this suggests that MS fixed this problem in later versions.

Answer (score 3):

Seconding **floele**'s answer; for more context, here's a brief analysis of the problem:

When the compiler processes an iterator block returning an `IEnumerable`, it generates a private `IEnumerable` class to hold the iteration logic. This is the beginning of the IL generated for its `GetEnumerator` method by the 4.0 compiler:

```
.method private final hidebysig newslot virtual 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<string> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.String>.GetEnumerator' () cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .override method instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>::GetEnumerator()
    // Method begins at RVA 0x57848
    // Code size 89 (0x59)
    .maxstack 6
    .locals init (
        [0] bool,
        [1] class DOT.Core.MiscHelpers/'<ReadLines>d__0',
        [2] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<string>
    )

    IL_0000: call class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread [mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread::get_CurrentThread()
    IL_0005: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread::get_ManagedThreadId()
    IL_000a: ldarg.0
    IL_000b: ldfld int32 DOT.Core.MiscHelpers/'<ReadLines>d__0'::'<>l__initialThreadId'
    IL_0010: bne.un IL_0027
```

Notice the calls to `System.Threading.Thread::get_CurrentThread()` and `System.Threading.Thread::get_ManagedThreadId();`. The generated method uses this to perform an optimization where, if the `IEnumerable` is consumed immediately [1], the same object instance is returned (saving the cost of a constructor call) .

The following is the IL generated by the 4.5 compiler:

```
.method private final hidebysig newslot virtual 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<string> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.String>.GetEnumerator' () cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .override method instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>::GetEnumerator()
    // Method begins at RVA 0x4830c
    // Code size 64 (0x40)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class DOT.Core.MiscHelpers/'<ReadLines>d__0'
    )

    IL_0000: call int32 [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_CurrentManagedThreadId()
    IL_0005: ldarg.0
    IL_0006: ldfld int32 DOT.Core.MiscHelpers/'<ReadLines>d__0'::'<>l__initialThreadId'
    IL_000b: bne.un IL_002b
```

Notice the two calls from the previous method are now replaced by `System.Environment::get_CurrentManagedThreadId()`, which is a property added in .NET 4.5.

Since the 4.5 upgrade overwrites the 4.0 C# compiler (csc.exe), code compiled for 4.0 on your machine will use the new IL template and will not run on a vanilla 4.0 install, unless you have the .NET 4.0 Reference Assemblies [2], which will cause the compiler to generate the old version of the IL.

[1] That is, the first time it's consumed on the thread that created it (e.g. in a foreach statement).

[2] It's actually possible to extract the .NET 4.0 compiler from the .NET Framework installer, and modify your project files to compile your code with that. This could be another way to solve the problem, but it's a long story and I won't go into details here

Answer (score 0):

Check your nuget packages all projects should have the same version of dlls.